# Centered text in matplotlib tables

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to center the text inside a matplotlib table cell, while the default seems to be right aligned. I looked through the documentation of the Table object, but I could not find anything useful in this.

Is there an easy way to achieve the centering?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try editing the sample [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/table_demo.html)

Adding

```
cellLoc='center'
```

To

```
the_table = plt.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      rowLabels=rows,
                      rowColours=colors,
                      colLabels=columns,
                      loc='bottom')
```

To get 
[image]

Comment: That was it. I do not know how I did not find it before, but thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

Another answer which edits the cell's alignment individually, serves this case and a more general one where only arbitrary columns (but not all) are to be centered (or any specific cells to that case).

Let's say you have a 5 rows - 3 columns table. If you want to edit only first column:

```
the_table = plt.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      rowLabels=rows,
                      rowColours=colors,
                      colLabels=columns,
                      loc='bottom')

cells = the_table.properties()["celld"]
for i in range(0, 5):
    cells[i, 0]._loc = 'center'
```

I was stuck with this until I took a look at `table.py` [source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/table.py)

**EDIT 10/24/2021**: As of today the above approach doesn't seem to work. It is however easy to fix it using `set_text_props` method of Cell objects (don't know if it didn't exit back then or I was unaware of it). To test it just add the following lines before the `plt.show()` of the [official table demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/table_demo.html). In this case the 4th column is centered.

```
cells = the_table.properties()["celld"]
for i in range(0, 5):
     cells[i, 3].set_text_props(ha="center")
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Morteza I updated my answer. I'd appreciate if you would remove the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

According to documentation, there is this metthod in cell object :

```
set_text_props(self, **kwargs)
```

kwargs may refers to text methods/attribute, such this one:

```
horizontalalignment or ha = [ 'center' | 'right' | 'left' ]
```

So, what about :

```
cell.set_text_props(ha='center')
```

Comment: Sorry, no more ideas.

Comment: Unfortunately the alignment isn't controlled by the text props but by the `_loc` attribute, as mentioned by Sabian (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40390950/4398595)

Answer (score -1):

Below method worked for me to change alignment for all cells.

```
col=5
rows=6
for i in range(0,col):
    for j in range(1,rows):
        cells[j, i].set_text_props(ha="center")
```